# Do I have to use a “using” statement in a short method?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, using

Do I have to use a `using` statement to dispose immediately even in a method? Or will the ending of the method cause an automatic `Dispose` of all local variables including graphics?
(I’m asking this because I’ve seen examples that have `Dispose` calls at the end of methods, and wanted to know if that’s really necessary.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you do. Going out of scope ***does not*** do anything; it does not call `Dispose()`, it does not garbage-collect, it does not call a finalizer.

If the type is `IDisposable`, then **yes**. It is your job to tidy up after yourself (assuming that the object is actually "done with" at this point).

Possible side-effects of not doing this:

- files get left open and cause access-exceptions (`FileStream`)
- connections get left open and cause pool saturation (`DbConnection`)
- unmanaged handles get saturated and cause resource starvation (any winforms/etc)
- transactions get left open and cause blocking (`TransactionScope` / `DbTransaction`)
- etc

basically, bad things.

Furthermore, in **most** cases where you see `Dispose()` at the bottom of the method, a `using` would be preferable. There *are* some cases where that isn't possible (fields on an object, for example), but the point remains: it sounds like those are bad examples.

Comment: But does it pass Go or collect $200?

Comment: @Andrew only if $200 is your pre-agreed severance for causing a wide-spread network outage by leaving a zombie transaction ;p

Comment: So (according to your comments to another answer) if I call `Dispose` for a `Graphics` – the memory will not be GC’d immediately, only when the GC will make its rounds?

Comment: @ispiro that depends very much on **which** memory ;p Calling dispose will release the windows-handle, and release the *unmanaged* memory; however, *GC* is not involved, and the *managed* memory is **not** collected

Answer (score 4):

You don't ever *have* to dispose of an object. But if you want to release unmanaged resources earlier rather than whenever the GC gets around to it (which is when it processes the fReachable queue)  then **yes you should** since the scope of of a method does not determine when a disposable object's finalize will be called.

For more you might want to read Jeffrey Richter's [Garbage Collection: Automatic Memory Management in the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

As delnan noted if there's a hard limit to the resources you're using you're much more likely to impacted if you let it get reclaimed by the GC rather than calling Dispose. DB connections are a good example of this kind of reasource and is certainly the reason why the [NumberOfReclaimedConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) performance counter got created.

Comment: Does the .NET garbage collector even go into un-managed space and clean up resources there? I was under the impression it did not.

Comment: The Dispose method might do more cleanup that the garbage collector wouldn't do.  It could close files, clean up network sockets, whatever.  If something is designed to be disposed, you should call dispose at some point.

Comment: You don't have to use line breaks either... actually, that's optional comared to disposing. If there's no `Dispose` call in the finalizer, you leak. If the finalizers are not called shortly thereafter by chance, you leak for a (potentially long) while. If there's a hard limit on the number of such resources one can have open at the same time and you're opening about as many such resources, you can easily run out of them if you don't dispose.

Comment: Actually if you don't call `Dispose`, you can end up in a situation where your managed memory is stil quite empty, but unmanaged resources are depleted. So please call `Dispose` as soon as you can. Once you don't need an object which has got that method defined, call it.

Comment: @MikeChristensen that's not quite right. `Dispose(true)` should only be calling `Dispose` on other Managed objects. If the finalizer is running the GC is currently processing fReachable queue. This means any referenced unmanaged resources are also being cleaned up at this point (which is later than what we want it to be). Just not via Dispose

Comment: @delnan I was sort of being tongue and cheek with my first sentence. I updated my answer to incorporate your comment.

Comment: Code which fails to call Dispose on objects which implement IDisposable but are not *explicitly* known to be tolerant of non-disposal is broken code.  Such code may pretty much work, but habitual disposal is far better than habitual sloppiness in such matters.  Note that not all cleanup code can be run from the Finalizer thread; objects should be *expected* to leak memory and resources if not disposed, even if some manage not to.

Comment: @supercat that's news to me. Do you happen to have any documentation for the expectation that objects will leak memory and resources if not disposed. If not perhaps you could add an answer that demonstrates this resource leak.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: When I say undisposed objects should be expected to leak, I don't mean that all, or even most, will, but rather that enough will that someone who ignores such issues will get bit.  Objects which attach to events from static or long-lived objects will often leak if abandoned, and objects which store information in ThreadStatic variables will often leak if created and abandoned within thread-pool threads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `using`. It is a great statement.

Actually if you don't call `Dispose` (either manually or by using `using`), you can end up in a situation where your managed memory is stil quite empty, but unmanaged resources are depleted. Eventually it can cause a deadlock because other objects or other processes will wait for your unmanaged resources and you will wait for them. (Garbage collector won't run, because managed memory still won't be full.)

So please call `Dispose` as soon as you can. Once you don't need an object which has got that method defined, call it.